# What is correct nginx location rules to match only the first path element in the URI to the CGI executable?

Tags: nginx, uri, location, mod-rewrite, match

I am using a FreePascal web module designed for apache cgi-bin  with nginx.

The CGI itself is called **spidersample.cgi** and contains modules such as **hello, bye** etc.

With Apache when **spidersample.cgi/hello** is called, **spidersample.cgi** gets executed, and passes control to the hello subroutine it contains.

With nginx instead of executing **spidersample.cgi** it treats **spidersample.cgi/hello** as meaning a **hello** file in a **spidersample.cgi** directory, and returns with a 404 error as there is no such directory.

I suspect it is an easily fixed problem with some rewrite rules in the configuration file and it is posted below.

=============================================

server {
    listen          8118;
    server_name     localhost;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/sysman_access.log;
    index index.html;
    root  /home/rchurch/Data/Lazarus/CgiApps;

```
    location ~ \.cgi$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/sysman_cgi.sock;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_n$
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
    }
```

}

==================================================================

Answer (score 0):

location ~ .cgi$ will match spidersample.cgi  //$ means end of the line

spidersample.cgi/hello match location ~ (.+)cgi/hello or (.+)cgi(.*)